# im trying to add a new theme on blogger but i keep getting this and i dont understand what i have to do?

Tags: html, blogger

Error parsing XML, line 353, column 3: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""

I keep getting this and im trying to change my theme on Blogger. What do i have to do to fix this

Comment: can you add some of your code? in blogger, switch to the html tab and copy all of it to pastebin or something and provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

You must self close the meta tag

Wrong

```
 <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
```

Right

```
<meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```